# How to prevent users from typing incorrect inputs?

Tags: c, error-handling

The program asks for a number. The program should loop the `scanf()` function if the user types anything else other than numbers.

The code is,

```
 do{
     printf("Enter row number\n");
     scanf("%d",&row);
  }while(row>='a' && row<='z');
```

But the above code doesn't work. I keep getting an error when typing in a letter. I tried manipulating around it and the whole thing loops infinitely.

Any suggestions?

Also how can I tell the `C Compiler` not to break the loop unless the input is an INTEGER?

Comment: The only fool proof way to prevent users from typing incorrect input it to not have any users!

Comment: Why are you reading a `char` with `%d`?

Comment: @dboarman, this is C

@Kenny, im asking users to input the number of rows, this is a sample only

Comment: you are telling it to pick up a digit while they type in an alpha... that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Gabriel, here I edited the code so that it asks for numbers ( although I stated it is asking for a number)

Comment: @Oded, I just read your comment :P Yes you're right, but in my case I really need to have users or else ill fail the course :P

Comment: self-duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796108/how-to-prevent-users-from-inputting-letters-or-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the return from `scanf()` which tells you whether the typed information was accurate for the conversion (`%d`) or not.  If it was inaccurate, you have to do error recovery, which is not particularly easy with `scanf()`.  Most people go for the approach of 'read a line of input and then parse it', where the error recovery is simpler.

---

> I understand that return values as essential in error checking, but how do I scan if its numbers or letters? Can I say if (input!=(integers)) or anything similar?

This is why people don't use `scanf()`.  If you get the line of data into a buffer (character array), then you can check the contents of the array as often as you like.  If you use `scanf()`, you don't get a reliable chance to process the data until after `scanf()` decides it has an error.

The functions (usually also available as macros) in `<ctype.h>` allow you to classify characters.  The functions in `<stdlib.h>` provide reliable conversions from strings to integers of various sorts.

So, you can think about doing something like:

```
char buffer[256];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
{
    ...check contents of buffer using isdigit() etc...
    ...or just plough ahead with...
    long value;
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    value = strtol(buffer, &end, 0);
    if (errno != 0 || (*end != '\0' && !isspace(*end))
        ...diagnose problems...
}
```

---

> This code is a bit out of my league at the moment .. is there a simpler way?

Well, I suppose you can use `atoi()` instead of `strtol()`, which simplifies the error handling (because it is less precise):

```
char buffer[256];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
{
    int value = atoi(buffer);
    if (value == 0)
    {
        puts("zero read - exiting loop");
        break;
    }
}
```

It doesn't get much simpler than this.  I don't know which part of the previous solution you felt was beyond you.  The alternatives, it seems to me, are much fiddlier, involving reading one character at a time and saving the digits and rejecting the non-digits:

```
char buffer[256];
char *dst = buffer;
int c;
int value;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        *dst++ = c;  /* Ignoring buffer overflow - bad! */
    }
    else if (isspace(c))
    {
        *dst = '\0';
        value = atoi(buffer);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unexpected character '%c'!\n", c);
    }
}
```

Etcetera.  There are various issues to resolve in that code - like resetting the pointer after an erroneous character, and avoiding buffer overflow, and dealing with signs on the numbers, and ... well, all sorts of stuff that I'd rather leave to routines like `fgets()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I understand that return values as essential in error checking, but how do I scan if its numbers or letters ? can I say if (input!=(integers)) or anything similar ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but this code is a bit out of my league at the moment .. is there a simpler way ?

Comment: @Zazu: The explanation is complete and the code simple. You need to reread it until you understand it. For example, the third code block in this answer was how one could do it but shouldn't. The second code block calls two functions that have been well documented since 1977. If you cannot learn what fgets and atoi and the structure of the while loop does, then yes, you are out of your league and should  get an introduction to programming. We won't write your code for you here, and we can't make you read what has been written.

Comment: @Zazu: Also, re-asking questions you already asked on Stack Overflow is kind of frowned upon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796108/how-to-prevent-users-from-inputting-letters-or-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read in characters, then determine if that character is a numeric and convert as needed.  You will also want to put in a check for some special character like 'q' or something to break you out of the loop when you are done entering characters.