# How to prevent users from inputting letters or numbers?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a simple problem;

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
 int input;
 printf("Choose a numeric value");
 scanf("%d",&input);
}
```

I want the user to only enter numbers ...
So it has to be something like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
 int input;
 printf("Choose a numeric value");
 do{
   scanf("%d",&input);
 }while(input!= 'something');
}
```

My problem is that I dont know what to replace in 'something' ... How can I prevent users from inputting alphabetic characters ?

**EDIT**

I just got something interesting :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
 int input;
 printf("Choose a numeric value");
 do{
   scanf("%d",&input);
 }while(input!= 'int');
}
```

Adding 'int' will keep looping as long as I enter numbers, I tried 'char' but that didnt work .. surely there is something for alphabets right ? :S
Please reply !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Remove tags 'limit-choices-to' and 'numbers', I think there aren't any kind of developer expert in 'limiting choices to'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent users from typing incorrect inputs ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795252/how-to-prevent-users-from-typing-incorrect-inputs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strtol` library function will convert a string representation of a number to its equivalent integer value, and will also set a pointer to the first character that does not match a valid number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
int value;
char buffer[SOME_SIZE];
char *chk;
do 
{
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL)
  {
    value = (int) strtol(buffer, &chk, 10); /* assume decimal format */
  }
} while (!isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0);
```

If `chk` points to something other than whitespace or a string terminator (0), then the string was not a valid integer constant.  For floating-point input, use `strtod`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and answering.
Pretty advanced commands used there, ill research about them to understand more :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent the user from entering anything he wants -- you can only ignore anything s/he enters that you don't "like".

A typical pattern is to read a string with `fgets`, then scan through the string and check that all the input was digits with `isdigit`. If it was all digits, then convert to an integer; otherwise, throw it away and get the input again.

Alternatively, use `strtol` to do the conversion. It sets a pointer to the end of the data it could convert to a number; in this case you (apparently) want it to point to the end of the string.

If you don't mind some non-portable code, you can read one character at a time, and throw away anything but digits (e.g. with `getch` on Windows).

Comment: I agree with your statement. But how do I implement that code in mine ? Do I use a do-while loop as well ? Sorry im not an expert in C :(

Comment: Yes, it's usually a do-while loop. `do { read(data); } while (!all_digits(data)); int value = convert(data);`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These commands are a bit too advanced for me xD This could be an easy way that you told me, but I just dont know how they work.
Thank you anyway, I am trying to find a way by manipulating ACSII variables .. Wonder if that would work ?

Comment: *"You can't prevent the user from entering anything he wants ..."* - sure you can ... with a suitably modified keyboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `scanf` to read in numbers - see http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-63.html

Use `fgets` instead.

However, if you must use `scanf`, you can do this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main() {
      char text[20];
      fputs("enter some number: ", stdout);
      fflush(stdout);
      if ( fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin) ) {
          int number;
          if ( sscanf(text, "%d", &number) == 1 ) {
              printf("number = %d\n", number);
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply..
How about using some kind of ACSII manipulation to prevent alphabetic characters ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would read the input into a buffer and scan that string for my number.

> char buffer[100];
>   float value;
>   do {
>   scanf("%s", buffer);
>   } while ( sscanf(buffer,"%f", &value) != 1 )

This will loop until the first thing the user enters on the line is a number. The input could be anything but will only get past this block when the first thing entered is a number.
example input: 
43289 (value is 43289) 
43.33 (value is 43.44) 
392gifah (value is 392) 
ajfgds432 (continues to loop)